# QProcess with QThread or QProcess.startDetached

Tags: qt5, qthread, qprocess

I was wondering if it is correct to use `QThread` to launch a new `QProcess` or is it best to use `QProcess::startDetached()`. Reading standard output is essential and starting a detached process does not let you read the stdout even if the `readyRead` signals are connected. Instead I was thinking about starting a new `QThread` that would then run my `QProcess` and that seems like a better idea when it comes to `signals` and `slots`. What's the best approach when it comes to reading the output and writing to `QProcess` that doesn't block the UI?

Comment: Why do you think you need an extra thread?  Just create a `QProcess`, connect to its signals and then call [`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) with the relevant args.

Comment: that will block the UI if the `QProcess` is kind of a service waiting for something to happen or waiting on user input

Comment: No it won't.  You should take a closer look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start).  Specifically `"Note: Processes are started asynchronously"`.

Comment: I see, then my issue is not in the `QProcess` itself but rather in the lifetime of my `QProcess`, since it's being scoped in a function call , if that makes any sense, since is what I'm getting `QProcess: Destroyed while process ("python") is still running.`

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  If this is just a scoping issue then it shouldn't be too difficult to solve -- if we can see the code.